# Error pasando un objeto a función de DLL de Matlab en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, matlab

Estoy realizando un desarrollo en ASP.NET/ANGULAR. En esa aplicación y en la parte de backend (API), debo realizar una llamada a una función contenida en una DLL generada desde Matlab.

La librería DLL esta incluida como referencia en el proyecto ASP que se apoya en el NET Framework 4.7.1.

En el momento de hacer la llamada le estoy pasando a la función un objeto de una clase bastante compleja compuesta de arrays de Integers y Doubles. Cuando hago esa llamada se produce una excepción del tipo "input data type unsupported by Matlab Builder NE"

Por escenario de trabajo todo se realiza sobre plataforma de 32 bits: Compilación de la libreria de Matlab, Runtime de Matlab instalado, proyecto en VS2017, IIS Express de VS.

Aclaración importante: **En el mismo escenario, si en vez de una aplicación de ASP.NET, es una aplicación de Windows Form (escritorio) todo funciona perfectamente.**

He probado un entorno de 64 bits a excepción de la dll de Matlab que no tengo posibilidad de compilarla en 64 bits ya que me facilitan.

He probado a incorporar la dll MWarray.dll y convertir los tipos .net a tipos nativos de Matlab (MWnumberArray) y tampoco

A pesar de haber consultado mucha documentación al respecto estoy bloqueado con esta cuestión.

Agradezco cualquier comentario que me aporte ideas.

Gracias

Comment: haz buscado documentacion de ese DLL en especifico ?

Comment: Hola Mike. Si. realmente la dll de Matlab la compila otro departamento y  tengo todo el acceso a la documentación. Parece ser un problema de  la compatibilidad del runtime de matlab con IIS, ya que como comentaba en la pregunta funciona perfectamente en la aplicación de windows form

Answer (score -2):

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=memory;deleteAfterServicing=true;" />
    <add key="EstacionDll" value="Data" />
    <add key="EstacionClass" value="Caborca.Data.EstacionData" />
    <add key="DatosDll" value="Data" />
    <add key="DatosClass" value="Caborca.Data.DatosData" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: Hola Edwin. Gracias por tu respuesta pero...te soy sincero...no la entiendo